# Set up a column based on another column and outside list in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column in a Pandas dataframe which takes only one array from a list of 5 arrays (the list is titled `cluster_centre`) and puts that array into the dataframe. It would take the array at the index that matches the value in the 'labels' column of the same dataframe (which has values of 0,1,2,3 or 4). So for instance, if the sentence in that row was given a label of 2 i.e. the 'labels' column value for that row would be 2, then the value of the 'cluster_centres' column in the df at that row would be `cluster_centre[2]`. How can I do this? The code I have attempted is pasted below:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd

with open('JWN_Nordstrom_MDNA_overview_2017.txt', 'r') as file:
    initial_corpus = file.read()

corpus = initial_corpus.split('. ')

# Extract sentence embeddings
embedder = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-wikipedia-sections-mean-tokens')
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus)

# Perform KMeans clustering
num_clusters = 5
clustering_model = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
clustering_model.fit(corpus_embeddings)
cluster_assignment = clustering_model.labels_
cluster_centre = clustering_model.cluster_centers_

# Create dataframe
All_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
All_data_df['sentences'] = corpus
All_data_df['embeddings'] = corpus_embeddings
All_data_df['labels'] = cluster_assignment

# The line below creates a ValueError
All_data_df['cluster_centres'] = cluster_centre[All_data_df['labels']]
print(All_data_df.head())
```

I get this error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 768, placement implies 1`

UPDATE: I did some new stuff and tried this:

```
All_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
All_data_df['sentences'] = corpus
All_data_df['embeddings'] = corpus_embeddings
All_data_df['labels'] = cluster_assignment
#All_data_df['cluster_centres'] = 0

for index, row in All_data_df.iterrows():
    iforval = cluster_centre[row['labels']]
    All_data_df.at[index, 'cluster_centres'] = iforval
print(All_data_df.head())
```

But get a new error: `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`. I printed `iforval` inside the loop and it does indeed return 29 correct arrays from the `cluster_centre` list, which matches the 29 rows present in the dataframe. Now I just need to put them into the new column of the dataframe, but .at[] didn't work, not sure if I am using it correctly.

EDIT/UPDATE: Ok I found a sort of solution, don't know why I didn't realise this before, I just created a list beforehand and made that into the new column, ended up being much simpler.

```
cluster_centres_list = [cluster_centres[label] for label in cluster_assignment]

all_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
all_data_df['sentences'] = corpus
all_data_df['embeddings'] = corpus_embeddings
all_data_df['labels'] = cluster_assignment
all_data_df['cluster_centres'] = cluster_centres_list
print(all_data_df.head())
```

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_underscores` style. Don't use `.iterrows()`, it's both notoriously slow and not the most idiomatic.

Comment: So... how else can I accomplish this task then?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the operation you want to perform, could you maybe give an example? Also, have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: Yes, I have read a lot of Pandas documentation. Also, I do give an example in the first paragraph.

Comment: Maybe to explain it a different way, I basically want to take the values of the variable `iforval` calculated during the for loop and place them into a new column in the dataframe. Using .at[] didn't work. If there's a way to do so without iterrows() that's fine too.

Comment: What's the type of `cluster_centre`? You can probably do something along the lines of `all_data_df['cluster_centres'] = cluster_centre[all_data_df['labels']]`

Comment: It is a list, and if you check the end of code block 1, that's exactly what I did do, but it returned a ValueError. In any case, I figured out a decent solution by just creating a new list with the 29 cluster_centre embeddings using a list comprehension and then creating the new column from that list. Thanks anyway for the help, I renamed my variables,etc as you suggested.

Comment: _that’s exactly what I did do, but it returned a ValueError_ Hmm, what’s the full error message? Can you make a [mcve]?